# How to get large amounts of href links of very large contents of website with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am parsing a large html website that has over 1000 href links. I am using Beautifulsoup to get all the links but second time when I run the program again, beautifulsoup cannot handle it. (find specific all 'td' tags. how will I overcome this problem? Though I can load the html page with urllib, all the links cannot be printed. When I use it with find one 'td' tag, it is passed.

```
Tag = self.__Page.find('table', {'class':'RSLTS'}).findAll('td')    
    print Tag           

    for a in Tag.find('a', href= True):
        print "found", a['href']
```

Now working as

Tag = self.__Page.find('table', {'class':'RSLTS'}).find('td')
        print Tag

```
    for a in Tag.find('a', href= True):
        print "found", a['href']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over them:

```
tds = self.__Page.find('table', class_='RSLTS').find_all('td')

for td in tds:
    a = td.find('a', href=True)

    if a:
        print "found", a['href']
```

Although I'd just use lxml if you have a ton of stuff:

```
root.xpath('table[contains(@class, "RSLTS")]/td/a/@href')
```

Comment: tds = self.__Page.find('table', class_='RSLTS').find_all('td') is not working due to over 1000 'td'. I tried to install lxml but cannot import lxml.html.fromstring. Now I am trying to remove the lxml I previously installed. Python libraries are difficult to install on windows.

Comment: When the program reaches the first line 'findall('td')', it hungs. I cannot see any result anymore.

Comment: I got the solution because the constructor of __init__(self) connot hold the entire tag from beautifulsoup.